# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I cannot open some sites due to this error in Google Chrome (version: 48.0.2564.82 )
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

It is an https site.
Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default SSL/TLS settings for browsers keep getting tightened to eliminate older settings that are no longer secure.

The site in question most likely is still using an old, insecure configuration that Chrome will not support.

Try putting the URL into this tool: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
to check it for issues.

Comment: What information from this website is important to look at?

Comment: It would be easier if you could share the URL

Comment: You start by checking for anything in RED :)

Comment: Already found it I think :)
"This server uses only RC4 suites, which are insecure. From early 2016, modern browsers won't connect to it." Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help. Now you just need to get the site owner(s) to update.

Answer (score 1):

See may answer at https://superuser.com/a/1434714/182803, try to temporarily allow older TLS versions:

Disabling TLS 1.3 downgrade hardening in Chrome helped. open following URL in Chrome (works for version 74, but not for canary version 76): chrome://flags/#enforce-tls13-downgrade

In Firefox goto about:config and search for security.tls.version.fallback-limit set it temporarily to 1.

Make sure to return back to a more secure setting later.